# laravel request can not save quote character

Tags: php, laravel, insert, laravel-5.3

I want to ask

For Example :

```
$data = new Datasiswa();
   $data->name = $request->name;
$data->save();

//After Insert name = Roq'ie

$data = new Datasiswa();
   $data->name = 'Roq'ie';
$data->save();
```

Then the error appears

How to solve the above problem?
thank you

Comment: `$data->name = 'Roq\'ie';`

Answer (score 0):

to scape a quote and others special caracters you can use the \

example

for scape quote and double quote 
    \' and \''

Answer (score 0):

```
$data->name = <<<NOM
Roq'ie
NOM;
```

{Sarcasm}

You don't really need to use a HEREDOC (but you could).  Just do `"Roq'ie"` or `'Roq\'ie'`

I guess you could use NEWDOC too.

```
$data->name = <<<'NOM'
Roq'ie
NOM;
```

LMAO